# c++ Program not throwing any errors BoxOfProduce

Tags: c++, windows

I am writing a program for homework.  I have the following code.  The requirements are as follows:

Your Community Supported Agriculture (CSA) farm delivers a box of fresh fruits and vegeta-bles to your house once a week. For this programming project, de ne the class BoxOfProduce that contains exactly three bundles of fruits or vegetables. You can represent the fruits or vegetables as an array of type string. Add appropriate constructors and accessor/mutator functions to get or set the fruits or vegetables stored in the array. Also write an output function that displays the complete contents of the box on the console.

Next, write a main function that creates a BoxOfProduce with three items randomly selected from this list:

Broccoli
Tomato Kiwi
Kale
Tomatillo

Do not worry if your program randomly selects duplicate produce for the three items. Next, the main function should display the contents of the box and allow the user to substitute any one of the ve possible fruits or vegetables for any of the fruits or vegetables selected for the box. After the user is done with substitutions it should output the nal contents of the box to be delivered. Then it should ask if the user wants to create another box and if yes, it should repeat the above steps. It should keep doing so until the user chooses not to create another box of produce.

Finally, add a static variable to your class that keeps track of the total number of boxes of produce created and a static function that returns that value. Display this value in the main function at the end of each iteration of the main loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

  class BoxOfProduce
{
  public:

      BoxOfProduce();
      void displayWord(int boxee);
      void input();
      void output();
      string Box[]; 
  private: 

      string full_list[5];
      static int count;

};
    int BoxOfProduce::count=0;
        BoxOfProduce::BoxOfProduce()
  {
    full_list[0] = ("Broccoli");
    full_list[1] = ("Tomato");
    full_list[2] = ("Kiwi");
    full_list[3] = ("Kale");
    full_list[4] = ("Tomatillo");
  }


 void BoxOfProduce::input()
    {

    }      
void BoxOfProduce::output()
{
    cout<<"your bundle: ";
    for(int i=0; i < 3; i++) 
    {
        srand(time(0));
        int boxee = rand()% 5;
        Box[i] = full_list[boxee]; 
        displayWord( boxee); 
    }
}
void BoxOfProduce::displayWord(int boxee)
{
    cout << Box[boxee]<<endl;
}
int main()      
{
    BoxOfProduce b1;
    b1.input();
    b1.output();
}
```

When I run the program, it shows no errors or exceptions, the program compiles, starts and then a Windows error pops up and says "The program has stopped running."  Does anyone see anything wrong with this?

Comment: What are you trying to do when you say`string Box[];`? Also, getting outside help might be a violation of your school's academic honesty policy. (At a minimum, you will need to cite your sources.)

Comment: `srand()` should (usually) only be called once in a program. Put it as the first statement of main. Looks like Raymond spotted the problem, though. It should be `string Box[3];`.